# How do I refresh an MS Access form using VBA in the OnClose event of a different form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using MS Access with an ODBC Connection to a SQL Server. I need to be able to refresh the datasource of Form1 when Form2 closes. Form1 will be opened when Form2 closes. I used to be able to do this using an .adp Project but am having problems getting it to work with an ODBC connected .accdb database.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. 
Forms!Form1.Requery